# remove full path, keep filename only

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Trying to remove the full url that is being returned to imgurl:
Usually returns something like http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/filename.jpg
or http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/images/filename.jpg

I'd like to strip off everything except filename.jpg and return it to
ahng_photos_upload_image.  Strip off everything to the last forward-slash.
How can I do that with Jquery?

```
window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
jQuery('#ahng_photos_upload_image').val(imgurl);
tb_remove();
}
```

Comment: txt.substring(txt.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for that, just plain old JavaScript will do :)

```
alert('http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/filename.jpg'.split('/').pop());​​
```

In your case:

```
var filename = imgurl.split('/').pop();
```

Comment: Works like a charm.  Thanks.  I'll have to do a search to see how the split() and pop() work.

Comment: @nevermind Actually, the paths in linux are `/`. They are `\` in windows. But it wouldn't matter anyway, since we're talking about URLs which are always `/` and not paths.

Comment: @Andy if the path came from a url it may work, but when you try to upload a file the value of the input would be something like: "C:\fakepath\filename.txt" (tested on my localhost on Ubuntu in Chromium). So, for that reason, I personally prefer the regex way.

Answer (score 4):

you can use a regular expression in order to achieve this..

```
var file = imgUrl.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
```

Now the file would consist of only the file name ..

Answer (score 1):

If you're pretty confident that the URLs don't have funny stuff like hashes or parameters, a regex like this would do it:

```
var filename = imgurl.replace(/^.*\/([^/]*)$/, "$1");
```

Also: don't forget to declare "imgurl" with `var`, and you should *probably* use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` if your version of jQuery is 1.6 or newer:

```
var imgurl = jQuery('img', html).prop('src');
```

Also jQuery internally turns the two-argument form of the function into this:

```
var imgurl = jQuery(html).find('img').prop('src');
```

so you might as well code it that way.

Answer (score 1):

One further option:

```
var filename = imgurl.substring(imgurl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LzqGe/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
imgurl.split('/').slice(-1);
```

**Edit:** Look at [the version of @Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9353346/392725) who uses the `pop()` method, the latter being faster than `slice(-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have

```
var filename = imgurl.split('/').slice(-1);
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you don't know if you have forward or backward slashes, you are better off using the RE version of split:

```
"path".split(/[\/\\]/).slice(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that will work when your file name is like ./file.jpg

```
var extension = fileName.slice((fileName.lastIndexOf(".") - 1 >>> 0) + 2);
var baseName = fileName.replace(/^.*\/([^/]*)$/, "$1");
var path = fileName.replace(/(^.*\/)([^/]*)$/, "$1");
```